# Custom 'themes' compilation possible using brunch?

Tags: node.js, brunch

I am trying to figure out how I can accomplish the following using brunch. This is the current directory structure for our app:

```
--app
    --base (theme folder, considered the master for all themes)
        --sass
        --js
    --theme2
        --sass
        --js
    --theme3
        --sass
        --js
...so on
```

The base folder serves as a master for all other themes. However, if another theme has a file in the sass directory or js directory that matches one in the base folder it overrides that file in the base folder (this applies for imports as well).

I have so far created [this](https://github.com/deep-c/themes-sass-compiler-brunch/blob/master/lib/index.coffee) which works the way it needs to but it circumvents the brunch pipeline in that I write out the files (doesn't currently support file concatenation) and I would prefer to do this using the proper brunch pipline.

What happens is that each sass or js file it encounters in the base folder is used to generate a new file for another theme. E.g say the base theme has a file called `main.scss`. The path passed to compile is `base/scss/main.scss`. Now I want to use this same file for the other themes so I get all the theme folders and dynamically use this base main.scss file for each of the other themes. However, I also alter the inner imports to substitute files imports if they exist in the other themes directory. Its not the same file being spat into multiple locations.

The problem is that I want to dynamically generate new CSS files for brunch to render to different folders not related to the original path passed in (and thus the joinTo config option for this path).  By calling the callback, it automatically uses the original path parameter passed to the compile method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`overrides`](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#overrides) in your brunch-config to change your `joinTo`s to include `base` plus the given theme. You can also customize the build output directory or anything else for each theme if that helps. Then run each build separately using a command like `brunch build --env theme1`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply this gets me part of the way to a solution however it doesnt solve my problem in terms of overriding sass imports that are not compiled via brunch. For example on that github page above you can see the example where I override the _header.scss file with the one in in the themes folder. 

The problem I see is that each env override doesnt start the compile cycle again so i can. E.g if i had 2 themes + base the compile cycle for those same files in base is only run once regardless and then the output is placed in multiple directories. Is brunch suited to my use case?

Comment: This is in relation to  Multiple sets of overrides can be applied at once using a comma-separated list (--env foo,bar). Am i wrong in assuming this is to run/watch each env seperately? I could just write a bash script to run each individually when i want to build all my themes at once and then alter the imports since i then know what each env (theme) is.

Comment: For your first question, no, Brunch isn't going to do it the way you describe. In fact, nothing will unless it moves files around for you - sass resolves where to pick up imported files in its own way that is not influenced by the build tool. You should probably rethink how you want to organize your overriden styles.

Comment: About multiple envs, you have misinterpreted how it works. The overrides for each env are just laid over one another in the same way they are merged with the default config to result in one config per brunch instance. You wouldn't use this to build multiple themes at once - which is only possible if each theme is going to a different built file. To do that, you'd just define more `joinTo`s in your main config.